# com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

I am running my first mobile automation test case using appium in android studio.
I am using latest version of appium and android studio and Java 8.
I have set all the project dependencies.

But I have encountered with the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(Ljava/util/Comparator;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.lambda$validate$4(NewSessionPayload.java:199)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:373)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.<init>(NewSessionPayload.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:107)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:109)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:39)
at com.example.gourav.myapp.FristTest.setUp(FristTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.gourav.myapp.FristTest.End(FristTest.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Code for test case:-

```
    public class FristTest
    {
      AndroidDriver driver;

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException
     {
        // Created object of DesiredCapabilities class.
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // Set android deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ZH33L2CB5H");

        // Set BROWSER_NAME desired capability. It's Android in our case here.
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");

        // Set android VERSION desired capability. Set your mobile device's OS version.
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "7.1.1");

        // Set android platformName desired capability. It's Android in our case here.
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        // Set android appPackage desired capability. It is
        // com.android.calculator2 for calculator application.
        // Set your application's appPackage if you are using any other app.
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");

        // Set android appActivity desired capability. It is
        // com.android.calculator2.Calculator for calculator application.
        // Set your application's appPackage if you are using any other app.
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

        // Created object of RemoteWebDriver will all set capabilities.
        // Set appium server address and port number in URL string.
        // It will launch calculator app in android device.
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirstCalculator()
    {


        // Click on DELETE/CLR button to clear result text box before running test.
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button")).get(0).click();

        // Click on number 2 button.
        driver.findElement(By.name("7")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void End()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Please help. I have googled this problem but didnot get any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your project setup. Make sure you are using correct dependencies, for *gradle* it should look like:

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:5.0.4'
}`

**Note 1**: Since you don't start appium server programatically, server should be already running before you lauch test

**Note 2**: `driver.findElement(By.name("7"))` will **fail** because name locator strategy is deprecated for Appium, use `driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId(<your_value>))` instead

Comment: can you please help me with one more problem.

Comment: I am able to login into app successfully. but after login app get minimize automatically. hence web driver unable to find element present on the next activity (of same app). How to handle this situation.

Comment: try `driver.launchApp()`, it should restart the app

Answer (score 1):

I added the Dependency and its working well.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>24.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this definitely triggered the error without it, and made it disappear if it's added. Note that a few weeks ago all was working fine without guava ! That was before I added a new dependency oauth1.0...Note that my version isn't the same,30.1-jre, but that's secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium want to use ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet, but your guava lib doesn't have it. I checked and compared the file, if I use

```
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'
```

ImmutableSortedSet.java file doesn't have toImmutableSortedSet method. But if I use

```
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
```

it will be totally fine.

If you are in the same case, just remove the -android postfix.

Answer (score 0):

This is for maven configuration

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but i am using sbt, since my project is writen in scala, would there be anyone that have experience fixing this issue in sbt

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()'

```
 def makeDriver(platform: PlatformName, url: URL, dc: DesiredCapabilities): Option[WebDriver] = {
Try(platform match {
  case Android =>
    new AndroidDriver[MobileElement](url, dc)
  case IOS => new IOSDriver[MobileElement](url, dc)
  case browser: BrowserName => browser match {
    case Chrome => new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().merge(dc))
    case Safari => new SafariDriver(new SafariOptions().merge(dc))
  }

}).toOption
```